# probability of hashing into a bucket

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to solve the following simple probability question and I'd like some feedback for my solution.

> Suppose that $m$ strings are hashed (randomly) into $N$ buckets, assuming that all arrangements are equally likely. Find the probability that exactly $k$ strings are hashed to the first bucket.

My idea is to treat every possible assignment of strings to buckets as an equally likely outcome. Each such assignment is a $m$-dimensional vector where each value is one of $N$ buckets, $1$ through $N$. So this is my sample space.

My event is all the vectors in which $k$ of the $m$ places have $1$, and the rest have any of the remaining $N-1$ values. To count those, I have 
$\binom{m}{k}$ choices to place $k$ $1$'s in the vector, and ${(N-1)}^{(m-k)}$ ways to fill the remaining $m-k$ places, as each of the remaining places can have any $N-1$ values, corresponding to all the buckets that are not the first.

The probability will thus be

$$\frac{\binom{m}{k}(N-1)^{(m-k)}}{N^m}.$$

Is this correct?

EDIT: 
I came up with a python script that computes the probability through counting and agrees with my solution (unsurprisingly, since it counts in the same way)
Here's the code.

````
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)

def choose(n,k):
    return factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n-k))

# compute hash bucket assignment vectors
def cross_product(l1,l2):
    result = []
    for t in l1:
        for s in l2:
            x  = list(t)
            x.append(s)
            result.append(x)

    return result

# count how many of the vectors satisfy that bucket 1 appears k times

def count(l1,k):
    count = 0
    for vec in l1:
        d = {}
        for elem in vec:
            if elem in d:
                d[elem] += 1
            else:
                d[elem] = 1
        if 1 in d and d[1] == k: # if bucket 1 was in vec and it appears k times
            count += 1
            #print(vec)

    return count

# values for parameters
N = 4
m = 7
k = 4

l1 = [[x] for x in range(1,N+1)]
for i in range(m-1):
    l1 = cross_product(l1,range(1,N+1))

count_result = count(l1,k)

# solution 1
sol1 = (choose(m,k) * ((N-1) ** (m-k))) / (N**m)
print("Solution 1: ",sol1)

#solution 2
sol2 = choose(m-k+N-2,N-2) / choose(m+N-1,N-1)
print ("Solution 2: " , sol2)

# numerical computation
num1 = count_result / len(l1)
print ("Numerical result: ", num1)
```
````

Comment: Looks OK to me. I suggest you see if it gives the right answer for some small values of $m, N, k$ where you can check with a brute force listing. Check edge cases too.

Comment: I've done as you suggested and added a python script to enumerate the possibilities and the numerical enumeration agrees with my analytical solution. However, it disagress with @Anirudh's suggestion below which seems to me as correct solution as well. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> Let $n_i$ be the number of strings that land into the $i$th
>   of our $N$ buckets.

Now we can approach this problem using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). We are allowed to use stars and bars because we can treat our $m$ strings as indistinguishable since we only care about the amount of strings that end up in each bucket.

*Note that $n_i$ must be non-negative and integral.

Our sample space can simply be represented by the number of solutions to:

$$\sum_{i=1}^N n_i =m$$
Since we have no restrictions on where our $m$ strings can be distributed.

Using stars and bars we find that our equation has $\binom{m+N-1}{N-1}$ different solutions

Now for our desired outcome where our first slot only recives $k$ strings we simply need to find the number of solutions to:

$$k+\sum_{i=2}^N n_i =m$$
$$\sum_{i=2}^N n_i =m-k$$

Using stars and bars again we find that our equation has $\binom{m-k+N-2}{N-2}$ different solutions.

Thus our overall probability is:

$$\frac{\binom{m-k+N-2}{N-2}}{\binom{m+N-1}{N-1}}$$

Comment: I agree that your solution is correct but it differs from mine (in terms of the numerical result) and I'm not sure why. I've also edited my question and added the script I used to compute the values for my solution, your solution and also just enumerate the options numerically. Any thoughts?

Comment: To be honest I'm a bit stumped too your reasoning also seems correct.

Comment: Here's the issue: you cant treat the strings as indistinguishable. Even though we only care about how many strings there are in a bucket, the way you describe the problem means that if I swap two strings between buckets, it would be the same case in your model. Now, not all cases are equally likely and you cant just divide the event size by the sample size